# OCSP Errors - Firefox - macOS

Tags: macos, firefox

Certain websites are failing when I have "security.OCSP.require: true" set in Firefox. Normal websites work, but when visiting commonly used websites (Facebook, GitHub, Spotify) it fails 90% of the time.

What could be causing this?

**Firefox Version:** 84.0b7
**MacOS Version:** 10.15.7
[image: Firefox Screen]

Comment: Have you asked Mozilla (or any of these companies for support) why their certificate validation fails?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. [We are not a good place for customer support questions.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) Can you perhaps narrow this down to be about one precise web address and a specific screen shot of the failure message? Documenting your Mac and FireFox version as well makes this less of a customer-support question which is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple causes of this - it could for example be a server error, overloaded server, no route/path to the OCSP server, etc.

When the check fails, Firefox displays an error code that will tell you the reason. The text looks like this:

> An error occurred during a connection to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com). The OCSP
> server experienced an internal error. (Error code: XXXXXXXXX)

The XXXXXXX part will tell you what the problem was.

The problem you're experiencing is actually on of the main drawbacks of OCSP. By default, failing to check the status of the certificate online will just show you the page anyways - effectively bypassing the whole point of OCSP. On the other hand, setting it required as you did, makes it likely that you will experience web sites that won't display - even though you know they're up and running and "should" have been working.

The newer OCSP stapling standard attempts to remove the drawback while keeping the benefits by essentially letting the server do the OCSP check periodically, and keeping a timestamped, signed receipt of that check around for sending to clients.